# Which Unity API for HTTP REST is a valid replacement for Unity's obsolete WWW?

Tags: c#, rest, http, unity-game-engine

With Unity 2018.4.11f1 we want to use a Google REST API from a Unity application and found that a working example is using *obsolete* **WWW**.

Updating it with **UnityWebRequest.Post()** is always returning error *400:Invalid JSON payload received. Expected a value.*

The [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) says the default **Content-Type** header is set to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and the payload data seems to be converted into an *appropriately-formatted byte stream*.

Which current Unity API/Library can be used to create HTTP POST requests with a json payload (Content-Type: application/json), to avoid using obsolete components?

Answer (score 1):

UnityWebRequest.Post() does not actually escape correctly text.

Try constructing using UnityWebRequest.Put() and finally reset to UnityWebRequest.Post().

It will work

Answer (score 0):

The default is indeed `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you can change it.

Try the following

```
var request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, json);
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
yield return request.Send();
```

If you still have no luck with that, there's always the [.NET alternative.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Still getting  *"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected a value.\n%7b%27config%27%3a%7\n^"*, the data seems to be url-encoded anyway. Will have to look at the NET alternative, but I don't think it is available for macOS and the Android target platform...

Comment: How are you encoding your json string?

Comment: Like `String jsonStr = "{'config': {'encoding': 'FLAC', ... ` and also tried to explicitly use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` to avoid standard unicode, but nothing helps here. If there is nothing else, I will keep on using WWW. But I am wondering why newer APIs are not supporting standard HTTP REST with json payload.